# VBA Early Binding to Late Binding

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to convert PDF Files to Excel.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    
    Dim pdf_path As String
    Dim excel_path As String
    
    pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("E11").Value
    excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value
    
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File
    
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)
    
    Dim wa As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim wr As Object
    
    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    'Dim wa As New Word.Application
    wa.Visible = True
    'Dim doc As Word.Document
    
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet
    'Dim wr As Word.Range
    
    For Each f In fo.Files
        Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
        Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
        wr.WholeStory
    
    
        Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
        Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
        wr.Copy
    
        nsh.Paste
        nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))
    
        doc.Close False
        nwb.Close False
    Next
    
    wa.Quit
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```

The problem is, other people also want to use this function, but they don't understand to how to add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference in your VBA project. I tried to convert it to late binding, but it fails all the time. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more precise: What fails?

Comment: You show us already a mixture of late and early binding - why? Basically, you need to change only 2 things: Declare all variables as objects instead of the specific type (as you already do with the word objects) and use `CreateObject` instead of `new`. If something fails, you need to tell us what exactly fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The next code will automatically add the necessary reference:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

The above code may fail if `Trust access to the VBA project object model` check box is gray out,  being disabled by restricted administrative security policies. In such a case, the following solution should be recommended:

2. To declare and set variables in Late binding way, declare and assign the objects in the next way:

```
Dim fso As Object, fo as Object, f as Object
set fso =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

It is also good to be known that Early binding is operationally faster than Late during run-time, and the programmer may benefit of intellisense suggestions, automatic capitalization of method names etc.

Comment: Be aware that it is not in your hands if users trust the  VBA project object model and that it is switched off per default (and often is disabled in corporate environments at all)

Comment: @FunThomas I know that. Adding a reference gives you a larger view about the referenced object, using the methods of `IDispatch` to locate them and this is what I am doing first, at least for this spcific case. If not possible, Late binding is the remained solution when you must know the method to be used... Usually I am using Early binding when design the code and modify it to use Late, when post the code to not complicate the life of somebody not too skilled, from this point of view. Of course, when I don't forget to do it... :)

Comment: *You* know that. But the OP?

Comment: @FunThomas OP will try the code, if an error will be raised, goes to `Macro Settings` as instructed and if it is not allowed, switch to Late binding...

Comment: OP wrote "*other people also want to use this function*" - so if they get a code that tries to add the reference automatically but are not trusting the VBA model, code will fail - and that is not in the hand of OP and harder to explain then to explain how to add a reference.

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, you are right. It would be better to make some mentions after the code automatically adding the reference. Thanks!

Comment: Also Early Binding gives you access to any constants/enums in the type library, rather than having to use cryptic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
```

to this:

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim fo As Object
Dim f As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Comment: That simple? I can't accept that I couldn't do it myself LOL Thanks!!!